# Apache Ignite seems to cause session fixation

Tags: session, spring-security, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite to cluster web sessions, and use Spring security to do the form-based authentication. The software I use are:

- JDK 1.8.0_60
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.68
- Apache Ignite 1.5.0.final
- Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE

(Without Apache Ignite, the form based authentication works fine, and the JSESSIONID cookie gets changed upon the success of authentication to protect against session fixation attacks, as expected.)

With Apache Ignite, I cannot log in, and I get the following warning:

```
2016-04-18 16:49:07,283 WARN  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy/onAuthentication 102 - Your servlet container did not change the session ID when a new session was created. You will not be adequately protected against session-fixation attacks
```

If I turn off session fixation protection in the Spring configuration as below:

```
<http>
    ...
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
    ...
</http>
```

It works. (However as a result, the JSESSIONID cookie does not change upon the success of authentication.)

Comment: Can you try a nightly build and check if the issue is reproduced there? Ignite had a several related fixes since 1.5. The build can be downloaded here: https://builds.apache.org/view/H-L/view/Ignite/job/Ignite-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by Valentin (, thanks), I tried [the nightly build](https://builds.apache.org/view/H-L/view/Ignite/job/Ignite-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/) from Apache Ignite, of version 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT#20160419-sha1:186c8604. Indeed, it works.

It works with the following Spring security configuration:

```
<http>
    ...
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
    ...
</http>
```

And of course the JSESSIONID cookie does not change upon the success of Spring security authentication.

Then I comment out the following configuration:

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
```

It also works. And upon the success of authentication, the JSESSIONID cookie gets changed as it is supposed to do.

OK, I'll use Ignite version 1.5.0.final for now (with no session-fixation-protection), and wait for the release of version 1.6.x.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 has in-built functionality for session fixation,

- Changing the jsessionid on authentication to prevent session fixation attacks altogether

Tomcat is not letting the application to change the session ID.

Comment: But as mentioned in the question, without Apache Ignite, the form based authentication works fine, and the JSESSIONID cookie gets changed upon the success of authentication, to protect against session fixation attacks. In this case, Tomcat (version 7.0.68) does let the application change the session ID.